# Running a react app inside a linux docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker

I created a Linux container in docker with all the packages and dependencies I need it for my school project. I am aware you can deploy react app containers and use Docker for deployment, although I did not want that. I just need it a Linux container with everything installed so all the members in the team will use the same versions of npm and node. After building the container I ran inside my workdir folder:

npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start

and this is what it shows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTsBC.png)

which means that the app is running locally in my computer how can I see it locally in my PC?

Answer (score 2):

use this to run your image:

`docker run -d -p 8080:8080 my_image`

`-p 8080:808` - will map your docker container port to your localhost 8080 port, and you should be able to just go on http://localhost:8080 to see it.
(assuming that `npm start` is starting server on 8080 inside of your docker)

`-d` means in detached mode, your going to start docker and stay outside of it.

Comment: It is not working. Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint cs-space-zero_cs-space_run_d2561811c6df (af5cdf962a14886985b30b9d18ce473c8ce18f8314d0e09795ed61ba8dc6af46): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated
 That is the error I get. I do not want to use -d I want to be working within my container.

Comment: @specter_93 You have already an application using port 80, that's the reason for: **port is already allocated**

Comment: I fixed that but still does not solve the problem. When I navigate to http://localhost:8080 I cannot see the react app.

Comment: once in docker try duing `curl -XGET http://localhost/index.html` assuming you have index.html in your site - most probably it is going to return some error, which would mean that you app not working at all (`npm start` should produce some logs regarding this), thus no docker fault.